# Facebook SDK access token issue with Xcode 9.3

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I have just updated phone iOS11.3 and Xcode 9.3, facebook login goes crash like this from my old SDK call:

https://pasteboard.co/HeeRDVo.png

I didn't understand what that mean exactly, even it works with older versions. **Then I applied Swift SDK from that page,** https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/graph.

```
import FacebookCore

let connection = GraphRequestConnection()
connection.add(GraphRequest(graphPath: "/me")) { httpResponse, result in
  switch result {
  case .success(let response):
    print("Graph Request Succeeded: \(response)")
  case .failed(let error):
    print("Graph Request Failed: \(error)")
  }
}
connection.start()
```

**That gives below error log:**

```
FBSDKLog: starting with Graph API v2.4, GET requests for //me should contain an explicit "fields" parameter
Graph Request Failed: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=0, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=400, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=An active access token must be used to query information about the current user., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=2500, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 2500;
            "fbtrace_id" = ____id____;
            message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}}
```

It says, **An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.**

Even below code block gives same error when I made dictionaries comment line, because they don't work also.

```
import FacebookCore

struct MyProfileRequest: GraphRequestProtocol {
  struct Response: GraphResponseProtocol {
    init(rawResponse: Any?) {
      // Decode JSON from rawResponse into other properties here.
    }
  }

  var graphPath = "/me"
  var parameters: [String : Any]? = ["fields": "id, name"]
  var accessToken = AccessToken.current
  var httpMethod: GraphRequestHTTPMethod = .GET
  var apiVersion: GraphAPIVersion = .defaultVersion
}


let connection = GraphRequestConnection()
connection.add(MyProfileRequest()) { response, result in
  switch result {
  case .success(let response):
    print("Custom Graph Request Succeeded: \(response)")
    print("My facebook id is \(response.dictionaryValue?["id"])")
    print("My name is \(response.dictionaryValue?["name"])")
  case .failed(let error):
    print("Custom Graph Request Failed: \(error)")
  }
}
connection.start()
```

**What should I do to overcome this issue?**

Comment: _"facebook login goes crash"_ - and where exactly in that code you have shown you imagine any Facebook login to happen ...? I don't see you performing an actual login dialog call in there anywhere.

Comment: @CBroe It was EXC_BAD_ACCESS, I have added a picture point about my crash. It was working in objective-c based facebook sdk.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally I have solved my problem using below method instead of annotation open url method in the AppDelegate. Hope that it helps others who encounter with this problem in iOS 11.3.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app,
                                                                     open: url,
                                                                     sourceApplication: options[.sourceApplication] as! String,
                                                                     annotation: options[.annotation])
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I was almost going to revert back to Xcode 9.2 because of this error.

Comment: Does `options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication]` work as well?

Comment: @ConsBulaquena If you mean inside of the return value, yes you can use too UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey prefix, .sourceApplication does same thing :)